# Swift image upload saved as mime_type "data"

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, upload

I'm trying to upload (ios swift app) a bunch of URL params and an image to create an account on a server (node express).  Everything seems to work well, except the image, once saved on the server is showing as file type "data", and therefore won't display in a browser. Its worth noting that the images I'm trying are taken using the iphone camera as part of the sign up form. The data posts correctly, the file saves correctly (well, the name does and in the right place) and the response is correctly received.

Is there something I'm missing about httpbody? This works as expected from a browser and from my android app, so I suspect it's something in the either swift httpbody, or node multer and bodyparser.
Any help, or a shove in the right direction would be helpful, thanks!
The ios method

```
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: (self.url + path) as String)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var boundary = generateBoundaryString()
    request.setValue(NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary) as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var body = NSMutableData()
    if data.count > 0  {
        for( key, value ) in data {

            body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", (key as? String)!).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            if let string = value as? String {
                body.appendData(NSString(format: "%@\r\n", string).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            } else if let num = value as? Int {
                body.appendData(NSString(format: "%u\r\n", num).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
            }
        }
    }
    if image != nil {
        var imageData:NSData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1))
        var filename = "profile_\(Int64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970*1000)).jpg"
        var mime_type = "image/jpeg"

        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", filename).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", mime_type).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(imageData)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }
    body.appendData(NSString(format: "--%@--\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    request.HTTPBody = body

    request.setValue(NSString(format: "%d", body.length) as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    return request
```

The node that accepts the request (using multer and express)

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(multer({
    dest: './uploads',
    rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + Date.now()
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

Changed this line:

```
body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", filename).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

to this:

```
body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_image\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
```

The extra "\r\n" after filename was some how messing with the file, even though the content type follows the name, not the image data itself.

Go figure.  Literally 4 hours of trial and error, and I solved it 10 minutes after posting to SO.